# Example of triangulated category with vanishing $K_0$

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, triangulated-categories

Let $R$ be a ring, let $\operatorname{Perf}(R)$ the category of perfect modules over $R$. Suppose we have $E$ an perfect $R$-module (concentrated in degree $0$) such that its class $[E]\in K_0(R)$ is null. Consider the pre-triangulated subcategory $C\subset \operatorname{Perf}(R)$ generated by $E$.
It is true that $K_0(C)=0$ ?

$K_0$ is the algebraic K-theory ($0$-th)-group.

Comment: The class of $E=R\oplus R[1]$ vanishes, but $E$ generates everything, so this cannot be true.

Comment: @pbelmans Thanks I forgot to mention that E is concentrated in degree 0.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "generated". Do you allow retracts ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi since you are rising the question, I'm open to all possibilities. What would the answer if we will (will not) allow retracts.

Comment: Actually, I realized the answer is no either way. I thought it would be yes if you didn't allow retracts  but that's only if the thick closure of $C$ is the whole of $Perf(R)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *no* in general: let $R= \mathbb Z$ and $E= \mathbb Z/p$. Then $[E] = 0$ because of the co/fiber sequence $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/p$.

However, by the theorem of the heart, $K_0(C)= K_0(\mathbb Z/p)$ (of course $C$ is not equivalent to $\operatorname{Perf}(\mathbb Z/p)$ but it is still true on $K$-theory) which is clearly nonzero.

Here is one situation where something like this holds: if $C$ is generated *without retracts* by $E$, and the thick closure of $C$ is the whole of $\operatorname{Perf}(R)$. In this case, $C$ is a so-called ''dense'' subcategory and Thomason proved that $K_0(C)$ injects into $K_0(\operatorname{Perf}(R))$ as the subgroup generated by $[E]=0$.

Comment: Nice!! What is a thick closure ?

Comment: Closure under retracts of a triangulated subcategory !